# How to dynamically build angular.json file?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular.json

**What I need?** I want a convenient and easy way to create configuration for an Angular application (which is described in the `angular.json` file) on the fly. The same way this is done, for example, with Webpack or Tailwind configs (their configs can be `.js` files that simply export the config as an object).

**Why is this necessary?** It so happened that my project has a lot of build configurations. Therefore, the `angular.json` file becomes simply huge and very difficult to maintain. Many parts of the config are repeated, because some blocks (for example, `fileReplacements` and `assets`) have to be written in full each time, because `angular.json` does not have a mechanism for inheriting configurations.

**How do I solve the problem now?** I simply created a `.ts` script that creates the `angular.json` file I need. And I run this file before each `ng build` or `ng serve` command. There are a couple of disadvantages to this approach.

1. For the Angular configuration, there is not even TypeScript typing for the hints to work.
2. Every time the configuration changes, I have to manually stop and rebuild the application from scratch. Although if you change `angular.json` directly, then Angular sees this change and rebuilds the application on the fly.

**Is there an adequate solution for this problem? Maybe a more elegant way? Maybe it is possible to use the `angular.js` file instead of `angular.json` in some native way, but this is not in the documentation?**

Comment: [maybe this will help you](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10612#issuecomment-522369886)

Comment: @oksd Thank you! But this is exactly the same way I'm currently solving this problem. I'm looking for a slightly more delicate and beautiful way.